# How do Pony constructors work?

Tags: constructor, ponylang

It doesn't look like the [Pony language](https://tutorial.ponylang.org/) has made many inroads to stack overflow yet, but you've gotta start somewhere...

[Here's](https://tutorial.ponylang.org/types/classes.html) the very limited info about Pony constructors, which isn't helping me understand what I'm seeing.

Here's an initial program:

```
class Wombat
  let name: String
  var _hunger_level: U64

  new anon() =>
    name = "Anon"
    _hunger_level = 0

  new create(name': String) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = 0

  new hungry(name': String, hunger': U64) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = hunger'

actor Main
  new create(env: Env) =>

    env.out.print("Started.")

    let wombat: Wombat = Wombat("Ernie")
    let w: Wombat = createWombat()

    env.out.print("Name: "+wombat.name)
    env.out.print("Name: "+w.name)

  fun createWombat(): Wombat =>
    let w: Wombat = Wombat("Bert")
    w
```

Let's rename the "create" constructor to "named":

```
  new named(name': String) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = 0
```

... and I see error:

```
Error:
/src/main/main.pony:22:26: couldn't find 'create' in 'Wombat'
    let wombat: Wombat = Wombat("Ernie")
```

... which suggests that all constructors are not created equal. Huh...?

So, let's undo that change.

Now let's try using the zero-arg constructor:

```
    let wombat: Wombat = Wombat()
    let w: Wombat = createWombat()
```

... and now I see:

```
Error:
/src/main/main.pony:22:33: not enough arguments
    let wombat: Wombat = Wombat()
                            ^
```

It's ignoring that constructor.

So, let's rename the first two constructors:

```
  new create() =>
    name = "Anon"
    _hunger_level = 0

  new named(name': String) =>
    name = name'
    _hunger_level = 0
```

... and now I see:

```
Error:
/src/main/main.pony:22:26: couldn't find 'apply' in 'Wombat'
    let wombat: Wombat = Wombat()
```

No idea what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Chris Double on the Pony mailing list.

The answer is in the [Syntactic Sugar](https://tutorial.ponylang.org/expressions/sugar.html) docs. We simply need to specify which constructors we're running. So I changed the anon instantiation to:

```
let wombat: Wombat = Wombat.anon()
```